# How Pillow optimizes the transparency in the GIF image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation, animated-gif

I have created an Animated GIF image using Pillow which is a count down timer.

When I inspect the individual frames of the generated image, every subsequent frame having some transparent area, however, I am appending the full image each time while generating the GIF.

frame1:
[image]
frame2:
[image]
frame3:
[image]

This optimization is good as it reduces the size of the image, but I would like to know on what basis this transparency optimization is done.

Code sample used for generating the Image:

```
  frames = []
  fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Assets/myfont.ttf',32)
  b = Image.open('Assets/pallet.png')
  b = b.convert(mode='RGBA',palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(b)
  draw.text((225,31), "10", fill=(255,255,255,255), font=fnt)
  draw.text((288,31), "10", fill=(255,255,255,255), font=fnt)
  draw.text((353,31), "10", fill=(255,255,255,255), font=fnt)
  bref = b.copy()
  draw.text((412,31), "59", fill=(255,255,255), font=fnt)
  frames.append(b)
  for i in range(58, 0, -1):
    copyf = bref.copy()
    df = ImageDraw.Draw(copyf)
    df.text((412,31),str(i), fill=(255,255,255), font=fnt)
    frames.append(copyf)

  f = BytesIO()
  frames[0].save(f, format='GIF', save_all=True,append_images=frames[1:], duration=1000, loop=0)
```

Comment: You compare image0 to image1 and set all pixels that do not change to full transparency, crop the remainder of the image to visible pixels and store the offset of where to place it. GIMP can do something similar if you give it several layers and export to animated gif. Somethings the like is pronbably done, if you want to know for sure, you have to deepdive into the sources of pillow. Good luck.

Comment: Anthony Thyssen explains it in some detail here... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/ It is written from the perspective of **ImageMagick** but the concepts are common to any GIF animation.